# pytorch code sudden fails on colab with NVIDIA driver on your system is too old

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

I had some code which worked on colab (gpu runtime) just a short while ago. Suddenly I am getting

The NVIDIA driver on your system is too old (found version 10010).

nvcc shows
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

I tried torch versions 1.5.1, then 1.13.0. Both keep getting this error.

There is a discussion showing other people having doubts. with no clear resolution.
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/27738

Anyone having the same problem?

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe.

Comment: This crazy thing. it went away by itself the next day.

Answer (score 9):

The light-the-torch package is designed to solve exactly this type of issue. Try this:

```
!pip install light-the-torch
!ltt install torch torchvision
```

Comment: This is particularly useful, as it can auto-detect the CUDA versions and install the appropriate software, and no need to specify any version in the command.

Comment: Unfortunately no effect

Answer (score 4):

I think this might be to do with the fact that [Google Colab randomly connects you to a GPU when you start a runtime](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#gpu-availability). Some might have different drivers installed, which could result in that error to display only part of the time, as you've experienced.

You can see the current version of CUDA by running `!nvidia-smi` in Colab. You can then simply install a version of PyTorch that is compatible with this version of CUDA. The [PyTorch website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#start-locally) can generate a pip command for your language/environment/CUDA version, and there is also a list of [previous versions](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/) and their corresponding commands if you have a CUDA version that the current version doesn't support.

This is what I got working with a CUDA version of 10.1:

```
!pip install torch==1.7.1+cu101 torchvision==0.8.2+cu101 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Late reply, but maybe it will help others to ease their problems.

[Pytorch has a previous versions page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/) that has both PyTorch and Torchvision installation commands recommended for older versions. For your case, I used `!pip install torch==1.6.0+cu101 torchvision==0.7.0+cu101 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html` and worked just fine in Google Colab, taking into consideration the NVidia driver version as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error.
This one fixed the issue for me:

```
pip install torch==1.4.0+cu100 torchvision==0.5.0+cu100 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

```
pip install torch==1.8.1+cu101 torchvision==0.9.1+cu101 torchaudio==0.8.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Source: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/userwarning-cuda-initialization-the-nvidia-driver-on-your-system-is-too-old-found-version-10010/141547/5

I'm not sure if it is important, but I ran this after I installed all the my other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue on google colab. Following [this github issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/37287) I downgraded to `torch==1.4.0` using `!pip`.

Since I had several other requirements, I am reading them from a local file like this:

```
with open('attribute_hallucination/editing_tool/requirements.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write("cupy-cuda101==7.4.0\ncycler==0.10.0\nfastrlock==0.4\nfuture==0.18.2\nimageio==2.8.0\njoblib==0.14.1\nkiwisolver==1.2.0\nmatplotlib==3.2.1\nnumpy==1.18.4\nopencv-python==4.2.0.34\nPillow==7.1.2\npynvrtc==9.2\npyparsing==2.4.7\npython-dateutil==2.8.1\nscikit-learn==0.22.2.post1\nscipy==1.2.0\nsix==1.14.0\nsklearn==0.0\ntorch==1.4.0\ntorchvision==0.6.0\ntqdm==4.46.0")
!pip install -r attribute_hallucination/editing_tool/requirements.txt
```